# Manipulating DataFrames in a function

Tags: python, pandas, function

I need to make a function that can act on any dataframe and perform an action on it.

To clarify, for example let's say I have this sample dataframe here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
               columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Which looks like this.

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

I have created a function that does something of this sort:

```
def ColDrop(df, collist):
> df=df.drop(columns = collist)
> return df
```

(assume > as indent)

What I'd like is for it to accept a list as the 'collist' variable and drop all of those from the dataframe stated as 'df', so...

```
col = ['a', 'b']
ColDrop(df, col)
```

Would look like...

```
   c
0  3
1  6
2  9
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Similarly I want to remove values from any dataframe based on its row, for example...

```
def rowvaluedrop(df, column, pattern):
> filter = df[column].str.contains(pattern)
> df = df[~filter]
> return df

rowvaluedrop(df, a, 4)
```

Would look like...

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
2  7  8  9
```

(i realise this second example may not work since the values are integers rather than strings, but i hope that my point gets across regardless.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `returning dataframe` back to `df` implicitly

```
df = rowvaluedrop(df, a, 4)
```

Comment: oh... that should definitely have occurred to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept it as asnwer if it helps :)